# MySQL: Do not ignore duplicate matches

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have the following database:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mytest`;

USE `mytest`;

CREATE TABLE `TestTable` (
  `TestID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TestValue` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TestID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

INSERT INTO `TestTable` VALUES (1,'Example1'),(2,'Example2'),(3,'Example3'),(4,'Example4');
```

I'd like to perform a query over such table where I can concat all the matches (even the repeated ones). This is, say I want to get the rows related to the IDs (1,2,1), I would like to obtain:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(TestValue SEPARATOR '|') |
+---------------------------------------+
| Example1|Example2|Example1            |
+---------------------------------------+
```

However, this is what I'm able to do:

```
mysql> select GROUP_CONCAT(TestValue SEPARATOR '|') from TestTable where TestID IN (1,2,1);
+---------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(TestValue SEPARATOR '|') |
+---------------------------------------+
| Example1|Example2                     |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table and `left join`:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(t.TestValue SEPARATOR '|')
from (select 1 as testid union all select 2 union all select 1) i left join
     TestTable t
     using (TestID);
```

If you want to preserve the ordering, then you can include that:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(t.TestValue ORDER BY i.ord SEPARATOR '|')
from (select 1 as ord, 1 as testid union all
      select 2, 2 union all
      select 3, 1
     ) i left join
     TestTable t
     using (TestID);
```